# Java compare char on string array

Tags: java

Imagine I have a String array like this:

```
String[][] fruits = {{"Orange","1"}, {"Apple","2"}, {"Arancia","3"};
```

If I do this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length;i++){
         System.out.println(fruits[i][0].charAt(1));
            }
```

it will print:

```
r
p
r
```

And if I do this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length;i++){
         Character compare = fruits[i][0].charAt(1);
         System.out.println(compare.equals('r'));
            }
```

it will print:

```
true
false
true
```

So here is my question. Is it possible to use charAt and equals on the same line, I mean, something like this:

```
System.out.println((fruits[i][0].charAt(1)).equals("r"));
```

Regards,

favolas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, provided you convert the result of `charAt()` to `Character` first:

```
System.out.println(Character.valueOf(fruits[i][0].charAt(1)).equals('r'));
```

A simpler version is to write

```
System.out.println(fruits[i][0].charAt(1) == 'r');
```

**I personally would always prefer the latter to the former.**

The reason your version doesn't work is that `charAt()` returns `char` (as opposed to `Character`), and `char`, being a primitive type, has no `equals()` method.

Another error in your code is the use of double quotes in `equals("r")`. Sadly, this one would compile and could lead to a painful debugging session. With the `char`-based version above this would be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly! Try this:

```
System.out.println((fruits[i][0].charAt(1)) == 'r');
```

We're doing a primitive comparison (char to char) so we can use == instead of .equals(). Note that this is case sensitive.

Another option would be to explicitly cast the char to a String before using .equals()

If you're using a modern version of Java, you could also use the enhanced for syntax for cleaner code, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] fruits = {{"Orange","1"}, {"Apple","2"}, {"Arancia","3"}};
    for (String[] fruit: fruits){
        System.out.println((fruit[0].charAt(1)) == 'r');
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `char` data type, which is returned from `String.charAt()` is a primitive, not an object.  So you can just use the `==` operator to perform the comparison as it will compare the value, not the reference.

```
System.out.println((fruits[i][0].charAt(1) == 'r'));
```